# Need to fetch a list of Authors for a given book using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to fetch a list of Authors for a given book using streams in Java.
I could fetch the books only
As Books is not linked to Authors, so I'm not able to fetch authors.

I'm looking for a solution using Java Streams only.
Thank you.
I used below to fetch list of books but it's not what I want to achieve.

```java
authors.stream()
            .forEach(
                author -> {
                  author.getBooks().stream()
                      .filter(book -> book.getName().contains(bookName))
                      .forEach(book -> authorNames.add(book.getName()));
                });
```

```
public class Author {
          String name;
          List<Book> books;
                                  
          public String getName() {
            return name;
          }
          public List<Book> getBooks() {
            return books;
          }  
        }

    public class Book {
      String name;
                     
      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }
    
    public class Library {
    
      List<Author> authors;
                     
      public List<Author> getAuthors() {
        return authors;
      }
    
      public List<String> search(String bookName) {
        List<String> authorNames = new ArrayList<>();
        // write your code here
    
        /*authors.stream()
        .forEach(
            author -> {
              author.getBooks().stream()
                  .filter(book -> book.getName().contains(bookName))
                  .forEach(book -> authorNames.add(book.getName()));
            });*/
    
        return authorNames;
      }

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Author auth1 =
        new Author(
            "James D.",
            List.of(
                new Book("Forest Run"),
                new Book("On The Moon"),
                new Book("Rising Sun"),
                new Book("Afternoon Sun")));
    Author auth2 =
        new Author(
            "Martha S.",
            List.of(
                new Book("Run Away"),
                new Book("Are We Moving"),
                new Book("Sun Is Shining"),
                new Book("New Moon")));
    Author auth3 =
        new Author(
            "Phillip R.",
            List.of(
                new Book("On The Rock"),
                new Book("Darkness Of Moon"),
                new Book("A Walk In The Park"),
                new Book("Rising Tide")));

    Library lib = new Library(List.of(auth1, auth2, auth3));
    System.out.println(lib.search("Run"));
  }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this:

```java
        return authors.stream()
                .filter(author -> author.getBooks().stream()
                         .anyMatch(book -> book.getName().contains(bookName))) //1
                .map(Author::getName)                                          //2
                .collect(Collectors.toList());                                 //3
```

1. filter all authors that have at least one book whose name contains the parameter, I used contains because of the example in the test, but replace it by `equals` if you require full and casing match
2. Get the name of the author
3. Collect them as a list.